# How to overwrite httpserver ErrorLog in golang?

Tags: file, http, go, logging

i need to overwrite the implementation of http.Server ErrorLog. 
I tried various examples that i found in stackoverflow and the git of Go, but none of them work for me.

When i try to overrite ErrorLog, i pass a logger who goes to a .txt file.

This is my implementation:

```golang
file, err := os.OpenFile("http_logs.txt", os.O_CREATE|os.O_WRONLY|os.O_APPEND, 0666)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalln("Failed to open log http_logs:", err)
}

logger := log.New(file, "http: ", log.LstdFlags)
srv := &http.Server{
    Handler:  router,
    Addr:     addr,
    ErrorLog: logger,
}
if err := srv.ListenAndServe(); err != nil {
    errs <- err
}
```

The output of my terminal is:

```
2020/05/29 15:00:28 http: TLS handshake error from [::1]:62016: remote error: tls: bad certificate
```

My goal is that output goes to my .txt file.

The line who doesn't have the logger i passed initially is:

In the standard http\server.go, line 1785 to 1796

```golang
if err := tlsConn.Handshake(); err != nil {
    // If the handshake failed due to the client not speaking
    // TLS, assume they're speaking plaintext HTTP and write a
    // 400 response on the TLS conn's underlying net.Conn.
    if re, ok := err.(tls.RecordHeaderError); ok && re.Conn != nil && tlsRecordHeaderLooksLikeHTTP(re.RecordHeader) {
        io.WriteString(re.Conn, "HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request\r\n\r\nClient sent an HTTP request to an HTTPS server.\n")
        re.Conn.Close()
        return
    }
    c.server.logf("http: TLS handshake error from %s: %v", c.rwc.RemoteAddr(), err)
    return
}
```

I trace the ErrorLog and the srv implement correctly the logger, but when a new http req enter (and my test case is to failed over TLS Handshake), it print out to my console, not to my .txt file.

Can you help me?, thanks!.

Comment: @CeriseLimón Thanks, already added the output in the post.

Comment: @CeriseLimón Thanks you so much for the hint, indeed i have 2 http servers and 1 of then i wasn't overriten the ErrorLog, is working fine now, have a great day!

Comment: See https://12factor.net/logs
Under linux, the easiest thing to is `yourserver ... > yourlog.txt`